# How to get document object through window?

Tags: jquery

the scenario is window is passed as a parameter to a function , and I also need to use the document of the window for searching element in the function. No idea about how to get the document object through $(winObjParamter).winObjParamter is the parameter passed to the function.

Comment: Also, http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `winObjParamter.document` to get the `document` object of the window.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window

Comment: it worked fine, I ignored js is script language, it can be very different from strong type language.

Answer (score 3):

[`document` is a property of `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.document), so you can access it like any other property:

```
var doc = winObjParamter.document;
```

The MDN article linked to above states that `document`:

> Returns a reference to the document contained in the window.